# how can I change spacing between author listing and left margin?

Tags: margins, titles

I am using a certain style that has a certain spacing between left margin and author names (listed as name, affiliation, etc. one next to each other in small blocks). There are only two authors, and for some reason, they are left aligned. I want to align the two-block author information so that it is center.

Is there a way to add some spacing between the left margin and the author names?

The author command is:

```
\author{
x\\
y\\
zzz \\
{\small \tt \{a\}@b.c} \\
\And
tt \\
ww \\
vvv \\
{\small \tt xx@yy}
}
```

Comment: So, your problem is specific to a particular document class then?  Anyway, just how much space do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this too much or too little?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{
\rule{1in}{0pt}\and
x\\
y\\
zzz \\
{\small \tt \{a\}@b.c} \\
\and
tt \\
ww \\
vvv \\
{\small \tt xx@yy}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: maketitle]

Comment: this is probably too much, but I think it can be controlled with the \rule. thanks.